# How do you pass props to a React component after importing it dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm running a Next.js, React, Ts project.

I have imported a React component dynamically into my page, with ssr set to false as the component contains references to window and these references to window would throw `ReferenceError: window is not defined`.

```
const myComponent = dynamic(
  () => import('../components/myComponent').then(mod => mod.myComponent),
  { 
    ssr: false ,
  }
)

export default function Home() {
return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>My site</title>
      </Head>

      <main>
          <myComponent name="Damian" age={27} />
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

However when I call it in my page I can't pass its properties to it and I get the error:

```
Type '{ name: string; age: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

I feel like I'm definitely missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply clone your component and can pass props of your choice.

```
let component = myComponent;
let props = { name: "Damian" age: 27 };

return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>My site</title>
      </Head>

      <main>
        {React.cloneElement(component, props)}
      </main>
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: Argument of type 'ComponentType<{}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<

Comment: Can you share the code sandbox link so that a clear picture can be attained?

Comment: Ill see if I can set something up, I cant share the exact code